# Missing signal icon on lineage os

Tags: lineageos, signal-private-messenger

I've just installed Signal from an APK package downloaded from [here](https://signal.org/android/apk/) on a LineageOS smartphone.
I performed the installation from a Linux laptop using adb:

```
$ adb install Signal-Android-website-prod-universal-release-5.32.15.apk
Success
```

Signal works OK, e.g. I could start it and set up an account, but I can only start it from the app list inside the system settings: There is no Signal icon at the top level.
I cannot find any documentation or any information on how to solve this problem.
Do you have any hint?

**EDIT**

Here is some more information.

- Lineage OS version: 18.1, build 31st March 2022.
- Smartphone: Samsung Galaxy A520F.
- With top level I meant the home screen.

Comment: By "top level", did you mean [(1) the home screen, or (2) the app drawer](https://www.guidingtech.com/what-app-drawer-android/)? Because, unlike installing from Play Store (there's a setting in it), installing by ADB won't automatically create an icon on the home screen. Otherwise, have you tried different 3rd-party launcher apps?

Comment: If an app icon is automatically added to the launcher depends on the launcher. You can add any app to the launcher by pressing and holding the icon in app drawer and then move it up to the button "add it to the start screen".

Comment: I have found it in the app drawer (thanks Andrew) and added it to the launcher by pressing and holding the icon (thanks Robert).